# What is the definition of a "tribe" in the Daevabad trilogy?

Tags: daevabad-trilogy, city-of-brass

In the Daevabad trilogy (well, *The City of Brass* is my specific example), there are different "tribes" of beings.  The tribes appear to have different powers, but they also appear to interbreed.

Is there any explanation for why each tribe has a unique power that the others don't seem to, and how those powers transfer to children of mixed tribes?  Is there an explanation for why there are such tribes in the first place?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using "beings" instead of "djinn" as the author herself does?

Comment: Because she refers to them as Daevas as well, and there appears to be a tribe specifically of Daevas who took the name of the entire race, and I can't tell if "djinn" refers to a tribe or a species :-P  feel free to edit if it will clarify